# Infinite loop when using filter for jsp files

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

When I make filter for all jsp pages, the browser goes into an infinite loop, 
but when I make filter for only one page, it runs correctly!!

Here is doFilter method, if some one find the error plx tell me...

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (debug)  log("AuthenticationFilter:doFilter()");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    HttpServletResponse httpres = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpServletRequest httpreq = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    if (httpreq.getRequestURI().indexOf("login.jsp") == -1 || httpreq.getRequestURI().indexOf("LoginServlet") == -1) {
   // if(!httpreq.getRequestURL().equals("/OSQS/Login.jsp")){
        HttpSession session = httpreq.getSession();
        String logged = (String) session.getAttribute("login");

        if (logged == null) {
            httpres.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            return;
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that the filter's `url-pattern` is apparently too generic, e.g. `/*` or maybe `*.jsp`. It will be executed on *every* JSP request.

In the filter you're sending a redirect to `login.jsp` when the logged in user is absent. A redirect will instruct the client to fire a new HTTP request. A new HTTP request will invoke the filter again when the request URL matches its `url-pattern`. Because the logged in user is still absent, it goes into an infinite redirect loop.

Apart from determining the request URL (as you did), you can also just place the secured pages on a more specific `url-pattern`, e.g. `/secured/*`, `/private/*` or so and then place the secured pages there, but the login page not. If you redirect to the login page, then the filter won't be invoked more.

Comment: thanx it work browser didn't go in infinte loop , and display login page , but when i change in url to private/secure.jsp it goes in infinte loop :( and didn't redirect to login page !! why?

Comment: Probably you still have a login page in secured folder? Did you change `sendRedirect("login.jsp")` to `sendRedirect("/login.jsp")` ?

Comment: the problem i found is that user get session even if he is not logged in ??? i don't know why, since i get session form http request in servlet after i assure from db connection , and then make  session.setAttribute("Login", "ok"); and that what i check in filter , here:
 String logged = (String) session.getAttribute("login"); 
 but i shock , user got session attribute login=ok but he didn't login!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Likely your logout code is bogus. Restart your browser to create a new session.